# net localgroup "Remote Desktop User" username /ad doesnt work?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I might be wrong but isn't `Remote Desktop User` a localgroup? When I do:

`net localgroup 'Remote Desktop Users' name /ad`,

I got an error that indicate `Remote Desktop Users` doesn't exists (error 1376).

But `net localgroup` clearly prints out that group name, so I'm confused now.

Answer (score 2):

Use  double quotes instead of simple:

`net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" name /add`

Answer (score 0):

What is the full syntax you are trying?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490706.aspx

See there ^^

to add a local user account called warl0ck to that group it would be:

net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" warl0ck /add

NOTE: you might need to run cmd as administrator

Comment: That's what I did, and you didn't get an error? (`/ad` is an alias to `/add` BTW)

Comment: C:\Windows\system32>net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" Chris /add
 ---
The command completed successfully.